# Dealing with classes that instantiate other classes using a DI container

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, dependency-injection

So my problem lies in that I want to decouple my classes, which I've achieved to some extent with a DI container.
The only problem I have now is dealing with classeі that instantiate other classes. For instance after querying the database you get an instance of ORMResult, which has a next() method that returns ORMModel instances for fetched rows.

Now how do I decouple ORMResult and ORMModel ? 
1)My first idea was to pass the DI container as a dependency to ORMResult, so that it could be used for generating models. But in this way I'm coupling ORMResult with the container.

2)The other option is to have an ORMModelBuilder class that I could pass to ORMResult, but seeing that I have quite a few classes like that, so making builders for each one might be a huge waste.

3)I could pass a specific function that build an ORMModel as a parameter to ORMResult (PHP allows passing functions as arguments). This seems to me the best idea so far.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can't you make a factory that builds the stuff you need to build. And pass the factory as a dependency in? Are those the builders you are talking about? If so: Why do you need one for each class?

Comment: Well I just suspect that if the thing gets big I'm going to end up with a huge class of multiple facory methods stuffed into it. Maybe its not that bad really, but maybe there's a better way.

Comment: Do you really need that much build methods? Of the things that are being build are of the same type, isn't the build process basically the same (just guessing here without knowing the API ofc)?

Comment: ORM ORM ORM - that sounds like a mantra and a component. As it's a complicated component, you should use an existing solution not develop that your own. Therefore, please consult the vendor of the component you use for your support options at the current stage you wonder right now about. Sounds fair?

Comment: It was just an example.